# MySQl deadlock when insert after check for existence

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using C#, pseudo code:

```
//option1:set the transaction as Serializable
begin transaction ()
try{
    //option2:add "for update" to the end of the select query string
    select id from table_name where name_col_1=binary 'new_name_1' and name_col_2=binary 'new_name_2'
    if (exist) {rollback;return false;}
    //dead lock exception when insert
    insert into ...(id,...,name_col_1,name_col_2).. (default,...,'new_name_1','new_name_2') 
    commit;
    return true;
}catch(){rollback;return false;}
```

id is auto increment primary key

name_col_1 is varchar(100)

name_col_2 is varchar(5000) with index(500 char).

When run the code on multiple clients concurrently, with the above code, with option1 or option2 (please check the comments in the above code) , sometimes "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction" exception is throw.

**When can such simple "insert if not exist" transaction can trigger a deadlock**? Since if no record exist, then nothing could be locked by the select and there is only an insert before commit. If  the record exist, then just rollback, how can deadlock happen?

Note: if both option1 and option2 are not present, there will finally be some records with duplicated "name_col_1 and name_col_2".

Comment: Will the query run successfully in MySQL?

Comment: @tcadidot0 The exception only happen sometimes randomly on race conditions.

Comment: Why you not use unique key and `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` construction

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev the column is varchar(5000) unique key not supported. unique key of 500 char will prevent some non-duplication to be inserted.